# Is there a simple way to clear javascript from the cache with google chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I try a few things such as ctrl F5,F6 and shift F5,F6. Also clicking on settings, then history, then selecting clear cache. Eventually it seems to work but then it seems like I have to have that script selected and there are lots of steps involved.

Is there a simple way to clear a script or all scripts out of the cache?

Comment: Why not just clear the whole cache?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + Del is a short-cut for clearing the entire cache.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I want to clear the whole cache. I'll check out Joshhua's suggestion. Thanks.